# What protocols does GVFS provide?

Tags: 12.04, gvfs

I want to document the list of supported GVFS protocols in Ubuntu 12.04 (e.g. AFC, AFP, and WebDAV), but I don't know how to list them, besides running `locate gvfs`, and I wonder if someone has already documented them.

How can I obtain a list of installed GVFS protocols, and how can I obtain definitive descriptions/specifications of these protocols in general?

Comment: I have made your question relevant for 12.04 and not 12.10, as we are not supposed to discuss versions that aren't released yet. The list of protocols will hardly be changed anyway.

Comment: We can always add a note later if any other protocols are added in later versions of Ubuntu, but there doesn't seem to be anything different for quantal at http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/gvfs-backends/filelist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Introduction**

I can give you an answer for 12.04, although this may not be a totally definitive list of protocols. Before we start discussing the protocols, here is a quick summary of the nature of `gvfs` from `/usr/share/doc/gvfs/gvfs-libs/README`:

> Gvfs is a userspace virtual filesystem designed to work with the i/o
>   abstractions of gio (a library availible in glib >= 2.15.1). It
>   installs several modules that are automatically used by applications
>   using the APIs of libgio. There is also fuse support that allows
>   applications not using gio to access the gvfs filesystems.
>
> The gvfs model differs from e.g. gnome-vfs in that filesystems must
>   be mounted before they are used. There is a central daemon (gvfsd)
>   that handles coordinting mounts, and then each mount is (typically)
>   in its own daemon process (although mounts can share daemon process).

---

**Protocols**

A lot of the supported protocols are listed in the `gvfs-backends` package and the tools you can use with those protocols are listed in the `gvfs-bin` package, which if you have them installed are available by right clicking the package in `Synaptic` and clicking on installed files to show the list.

Comparing the [gvfs-backends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-backends) package description and the list of installed files in `Synaptic` comes up with the following list.

```
archive://        archive files support
afp://            Apple file protocol support
afc://            access mobile devices such as iphone and ipod Touch
cdda://           audio cds support
cifs://           communicate with cifs servers
dav:// (webdav://) handles remote filesystems
file:///          access a local file, for example,  
ftp://            access and use ftp server
gphoto2://        PTP camera and MTP media player support
http://           open http resources
https://          connect securely with https
obexftp://        bluetooth support 
smb://            communicate with samba servers
ssh://            connect securely to server
sftp://           send files securely via sftp 
usb://            mount a usb device directly, for example,
```

This is just a bare list; to **do something** with these protocols you can use the `gvfs` tools on the command line such as `gvfs-open` or `gvfs-mount`. The tools are listed in the `gvfs-bin` package at [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-bin) and in `Synaptic` if installed.  Basic examples from the command-line are:

```
gvfs-open file:///home/mike/
gvfs-open http://www.askubuntu.com
```

The first example will open you home folder in your default file browser; the second will open askubuntu in your browser.

For examples to do with remote filesystems, see [this article](http://blog.colovirt.com/2009/12/07/linux-filesystem-gnome-virtual-file-system-gvfs-remote-connectivity-cli/).

As this answer was **not** supposed to go into detail on how to use the protocols, I won't go into great detail here, as there are other `gvfs` articles on this site.

Comment: The protocols are listed in `man gvfs` in the "Mount backends" section

Comment: And there are some protocols in `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/` that are not listed in man gvfs.